# Executing python script from command line: error with imports

Tags: python, eclipse, command-line, import, pydev

I have written a small script in Python with Eclipse, and it works when executed from Eclipse. But it doesn't work from command line:

```
>python test.py argument1 argument2
from src import Tests, ImportError: No module named src
```

The script is stored with the following folders:

```
ScriptFolder
.input
.report
.src
..test.py
..Tests
...Test1.py
...Test2.py
..TestUtils
...FileUtils.py
```

And this is the way I'm doing the imports at test.py:

```
from src import Tests
from TestUtils import FileUtils
```

About the **init**.py files, the one which shares folder with test.py is empty, and the one into Tests folder has this content:

```
import Test1
import Test2
```

And the **init**.py file into TestUtils has this content:

```
import FileUtils
```

The problem is that, if I change the line `from src import Tests` to just `import Tests` I'm getting error in Eclipse: `Unresolved imports: Tests. found at src.Tests`

How can I make it work for both Eclipse and command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys.path.append(path_to_src_directory)`

This will add a path to default paths where python looks for modules.
Since, currently the path to your src directory is not known to python, it gives `No module named src` error.
Also, your src directory does not seem to have an `__init__.py` file.

Comment: I don't understand why I need __init__.py file into root folder. Anyway, I am also importing TestConstants.py, which is into root folder, and works. I am importing FileUtils.py from TestUtils, and works. But it is not possible to import Tests. Why is that python knows where to look for those files and not the Test files? And how may I use the sys.path.append call? I guess an absolute path would not be a good praxis so, how can I use it in a relative way?

Comment: "I don't understand why I need `__init__.py`" ... "Why is that Python knows where to look for those files and not the Test files" The second question is the answer to the first.

Comment: @DanielRoseman But I understand its purpose into Tests folder, importing every py file into that folder, so then you can import all of them with just importing 'Tests'. But I don't understand its purpose into root file. In fact, if I edit root's __init__.py file and write import Tests, the problem remains

Comment: You have a path problem, like DhruvPathak is telling you. You would be wise to read the documentation on modules: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html "The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__` variable, described later."